# Сократить повторения от сочетаний/расстановок

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Нужно подсчитать количество возможных вариантов расстановок(?) без повторений, при условии, что минимум один объект занимает одну из первых трех позиций, второй минимум одну из шести первых, третий одну из первых девяти, четвертый одну из первых 12ти и т.д. (объекты идентичны друг другу).

Т.е., логично, что мы можем расставить четыре объекта 3*5*7*9 способами. Но каким образом вывести алгоритм для подсчета уникальных расстановок (отличных друг от друга  только положением) или получить количество лишних повторений из полученных 945-ти способов.

Появилась идея реализации через количество сочетаний

```
C(x,y)=y!/(x!(y-x)!)
```

где x - количество возможных объектов, y - мест для размещения. Т.е. для 4 объектов должно выходить что-то вроде

```
C(1...3,3)*С(1...3,3)*С(0...2,3)*С(0...1,3)
```

Правда, вопрос теперь, как такой перебор на python реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сгенерировать не так трудно, а вот простой формулы пока не вижу.

Для `[3,6,9,12]` будет 273 варианта. Младшие позиции в бинарном представлении справа.

```
lst = []
def perebor(current, limits, last, level):
    if level == len(limits):
        lst.append(current)
        return
    else:
        for i in range(last + 1, limits[level]):
            perebor(current | (1<<i), limits, i, level + 1)

perebor(0, [2,4,6], -1, 0)
print(len(lst))
print(["{0:b}".format(x) for x in lst])

14
['111', '1011', '10011', '100011', '1101', '10101', '100101',
 '11001', '101001', '1110', '10110', '100110', '11010', '101010']
```